# Multi-Dimensional collection in c#

Tags: c#, collections

I want to make collection like first element in `string` and second is `list` of object. list object can be either `int`/`string`. I don't know how to achieve this functionality. Pls help. Following kind of data I need:

```
Key            Value
mon_number     {1,4,5}
mon_name       {jan,apr,may}
quater_number  {1,2}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Key` is unique, you could use `Dictionary<string, List<object>>`:

```
Dictionary<string, List<object>> dict = new ...;
dict["mon_number"] = new List<object>();
dict["mon_number"].Add(1);
dict["mon_number"].Add(2);
dict["mon_number"].Add(5);
dict["mon_name"] = new List<object>();
dict["mon_name"].Add("jan");
dict["mon_name"].Add("apr");
dict["mon_name"].Add("may");    
...
```

You could also use arrays (if the type of the elements in the list is equals for all entries):

```
Dictionary<string, object[]> dict = new ...;
dict["mon_number"] = new [] {1, 2, 5 };
dict["mon_name"] = new[] { "jan", "apr", "may" }
```

Comment: can I directly add list like: dict["mon_number"].add(xyzList);

Comment: Hmm.. Means if I make list of mon_number like List<int> mon_numberList = new List<int>(); mon_numberList.Add(1); mon_numberList.Add(4); mon_numberList.Add(5);   and add it to dictionary like: dict["mon_number"].add(mon_numberList);

Comment: If you already *have* an object that holds your list you could just use `dict["mon_number"] = listObject` to create the entry in the dictionary. Then, later, you use `Add` to add an item to the list.